# MailCore2 - Fetch message content without downloading images or attachments?

Tags: ios, objective-c, email, mailcore2

I want to provide a preview of a user's messages, but I don't wish to download attachments just in order to do that.

The information I need is:

- Subject
- Date
- Sender information (display name if available, email address)
- Plain-text message

By calling the method `fetchMessagesByNumberOperationWithFolder:` with request kind `MCOIMAPMessagesRequestKindHeaders`, I get the date and subject, but it's very slow to return if any of the messages have attachments. By calling it with request kind `MCOIMAPMessagesRequestKindUid`, it returns very quickly, with just the `Uid` (and the current date, as a placeholder). From there, I still need to get the subject, the date and the sender.

Now I'm still trying to get this information, while avoiding downloading message attachments.

Calling `fetchParsedMessageOperationWithFolder:` or `fetchMessageOperationWithFolder:` both download the message with attachments, and are thus very slow to return.

Because `fetchMessageOperationWithFolder:` completes with a `NSData` object, checking the size of the given object reveals it to be the size of a regular message, plus its' attachment.

What can I do to get the information I need, without downloading any attachments?

EDIT: Calling `requiredPartsForRendering` could give me the content of the email, but in order to retrieve the Date and sender information, I'd still have to have a request kind of `MCOIMAPMessagesRequestKindHeaders`, which would download the attachment.

So to clarify:

I want to get the following information from an IMAP email, without downloading the email attachments:

- Subject
- Date
- Sender information (display name if available, email address)
- Plain-text message

Answer (score 3):

The following methods should be helpful to you:

`-[MCOAbstractMessage requiredPartsForRendering]` will return the message parts that you needs to fetch to be able to show the text content of the message.

`-[MCOIMAPSession fetchMessageAttachmentOperationWithFolder:uid:partID:encoding:]` will help you fetch each of those parts.

`-[MCOIMAPMessage htmlRenderingWithFolder:delegate:]` will return the rendered content as HTML (or nil if you don't provide all the content of the parts through the delegate.

`-[NSString mco_flattenHTML]` is also useful if you'd like to convert the HTML to a unformatted string.

Comment: I also find ```- [MCOIMAPSession plainTextBodyRenderingOperationWithMessage: folder:]``` useful for providing short previews of messages.

Comment: I re-wrote my question for clarification. I don't think the information you've given me solves my problem.

Comment: I think your rewrite of the question + the answer I gave answers fully to your concerns.

Comment: @DinhViêtHoà Which method or methods would you suggest I use to get the subject and date of a message, without downloading the attachments? `fetchMessageAttachmentOperation` will only give me the content, and `MCOIMAPMessagesRequestKindHeaders` will download the attachments.

Comment: MCOIMAPMessagesRequestKindHeaders won't download attachments.

Comment: @DinhViêtHoà Right, so that'd be ok, except it takes around 20 seconds to return, if there's an attachment in one of the requested messages. So I'm not able to check the size of the data it's downloading to my device, but somewhere along the line, it's taking 20 seconds with an attachment.